# Login Redirect Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I want to re-direct people logging in based on their role. When I use the code below, the roles are coming up empty when debugging - I suspect because they haven't been completely logged in yet? I may be tapping into the the wrong event, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn" runat="server"
    DestinationPageUrl="~/Login.aspx" EnableViewState="false" 
        RenderOuterTable="false">

<p>
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" CssClass="submitButton" runat="server" Width="70"
    CommandName="Login" Text="Log In"
        ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" />
</p>
</asp:login>

protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Overrides ReturnUrl page parameter
    //Response.Redirect(LoginUser.DestinationPageUrl);

    if (User.IsInRole("Member"))
        Response.Redirect("~/AskExpert/AskQuestion.aspx");
    else if (User.IsInRole("Expert"))
        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Experts/ViewQuestions.aspx");
    else if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/AdminHome.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Roles.IsUserInRole()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42.aspx) instead. `User.IsInRole` reads the authentication data from the auth cookie and it seems that this data is not yet set when that event is fired.

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Member"))
    Response.Redirect("~/AskExpert/AskQuestion.aspx");
else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Expert"))
    Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Experts/ViewQuestions.aspx");
else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
    Response.Redirect("~/Admin/AdminHome.aspx");
```

The downside to `Roles.IsUserInRole` is that if you're using a database provider, it results in a roundtrip.

Comment: Thanks your answer makes sense - I also noticed that my DB had changed during dev/testing and the user actually wasn't in that role!

Comment: Those issues are annoying, especially when some code you thought wasn't working may well have actually worked :D

Comment: Heads-up: I had to move your code to a PostBack block in the page load method to get this to work ;-)

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks for the update. Maybe your original code also works in the same location?

Comment: Had to ask question again as your solution caused issues with LogoutPageUrl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065430/login-and-logout-redirection

Comment: I've found a solution of sorts - add a landing page with security-trimmed links on that - just got this working and will update other answer. I may need to look at how to use cookies here?

Comment: Possibly. You could look into the `SetAuthCookie` method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx). This post may help if you need to do that http://www.danharman.net/2011/07/07/storing-custom-data-in-forms-authentication-tickets/

Comment: No problem! If you find a fix, feel free to post the answer in this thread and mark is as the correct one. I'm sure someone else will run into this issue at some point :D

Answer (score 0):

I usually avoid the go and back turn of redirection, transferring the control with Server.Transfer.