# Login and Logout Redirection

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-membership

I have a simple Web Forms login. The application has three roles, Admin, Expert and Member. I want to re-direct to a different sub-page for each. I also want to be able to re-direct to home page on logout.

I've asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003940/login-redirect-issue), but the solution overrode the LoginStatus LogoutPageUrl attribute. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

**UPDATE 12/28/2012**

So far, the only solution to this I have found is to create a new menu page containing security-trimmed links to the different destination pages. Leaving this question open for a while to elicit feedback / alternative solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the only solution to this I have found is to create a new menu landing (destination) page containing security-trimmed links to the different destination pages.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        adminLink.Visible = true;

    if ((User.IsInRole("Member")) || (User.IsInRole("Admin")))
        questionsLink.Visible = true;
}
```